# Bootstrap grid column auto adjust left-right alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I have div columns `Address`, `Postal code` and `Fax`.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-1">
... 
<!-- Address -->
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-1">
... 
<!-- Postal code -->
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-1">
... 
<!-- Fax -->
</div>
```

I want the Fax column to auto-adjust and fill the space below the `Postal code` column and beside the `Address`. using `d-flex` not `row`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Postal code and Fax components in same container. Please check the code below:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-1">
  ...
  <!-- Address -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 mb-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    ...
    <!-- Postal code -->
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    ...
    <!-- Fax -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but still, there should be a better way using d-flex. this is manual grouping.

Comment: Actually you solve this situation with css grid. But I could not find how to to with d-flex @AmitShah